# Meaning of absolute and uniform convergence of a sequence of functions

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, terminology

In *Automorphic forms on $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb R)$* $\S$11.0 Borel writes the following. $X$ is a Lie group (quotient of $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb R)$ by some group)

> Recall that $C^\infty(X)$ [$\mathbb C$-valued functions] is usually viewed as a topological vector space with the topology defined by **absolute and uniform convergence** on compact sets - that is, by the seminorms $\nu_{D,L}$ ($L$ compact in $X$, $D\in \mathcal U$ [left-invariant differential operators]) - where
>   $$\nu_{D,L}(f) = \max_{x\in L}|Df(x)|$$

There are no series involved, so I'm wondering what the "absolute" stands for. Or does it simply mean that the convergence is uniform for $f$ *and* its derivatives?